# Android USB accessory/ Host Mode

Tags: android, usb

I'm developin with the google's add-on package com.android.future.usb  to communicate with a USB accessory on Android 2.3.5 the app is designed to run specifically on Samsung Galaxy y , 
My problem is that the phone is refusing to install the app, i added the uses-library tag in the .xml, i went through the tutorial on develop.android.com...

IS there a way to get past this error,missing_shared_library,  from my understanding it means that the phone doesn't include this shared library specifically,
and since the added external jar file from the google add on lib to my project wouldn't be included in the .apk file that's going to be installed on the Android device, Is there any way to  communicate with USB on that device ?!!!...

Answer (score 0):

Did you take care of the minor difference because of using the Add On?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/accessory.html#usage

Comment: definitely i did that the misssing_Shared_library error has nothing to do with that from my understanding it indicates that the phone
i.e the Android version installed on the device- 2.3.5- is missing those lib com.future.usb and that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Guess this is the same problem as described here: [USB Accessory API on Samsung Galaxy S2 Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024801/usb-accessory-api-on-samsung-galaxy-s2-android) There is an answer by Naresh Noby which sounds promising but I couldn't test it so far since I'm lacking the device. I would be very interested to hear the result though.