# Android and Arduino USB

Tags: android, usb, arduino

I get the INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY when I am trying to work with USB:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hellowworld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <uses-library android:name="com.android.future.usb.accessory" />

        <activity android:name=".HellowWorld" android:label="@string/title_activity_hellow_world" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
                       android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest
```

If I delete

```
uses-library android:name="com.android.future.usb.accessory'
```

it lets me to compile, but it doesn't work after.

How do I fix this problem?

(The project set to Google API 10 ink.)

I am working with [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29) 2.3.7.

Comment: You can find the solution to the problem in

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024801/usb-accessory-api-on-samsung-galaxy-s2-android